# I am using Nebular Version 10.0.x theme I want to overwrite scss using mixin nb-for-themes() but its not working

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, scss-mixins, nebular

I am using Nebular Version 10.0.x theme I want to overwrite scss using mixin nb-for-themes() but its not working after include use in custom scss file
I want to overwrite scss code with help of mixin nb-for-themes() with passing argument.
Given bellow code i want to change nav-bar header background
@include nb-for-themes(material-light,dark) {}